# Several profiles for same user in keycloak

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

I need your help with the following question I need to provide the ability to the user creates several profiles inside my app (I use keycloak for login and SSO) e.g. let's imagine that user wants to have two profiles within my application:

1. Name: Bruce Wayne, email: brucew@example.com, login: bruce.wayne and
   password:  secret
2. Name: Dark Knight, email: batman@example.com, login: bruce.wayne
   and password:  secret (credentials to login are the same)

Bruce logs into my app using his creds (login: bruce.wayne and password:  secret) and when he decides to use his account for 3rd resource using SSO he can select which profile about himself to share with this 3rd party resource - Bruce Wayne (businessman) or Dark Knight (batman, superhero). Is it possible to implement such use case using keycloak? Thanks.